# Angular service function isn't working on user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn how to make angular services, so I' ve made one but it only works as the page loads and it gives input value instead of function result.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="hexVal">
<p>Hex service: {{hex(hexVal)}}</p>
```

JS:

Service itself:

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    };
});
```

Usage of service:

```
$scope.hexVal = 255;
$scope.hex = function(arg){
    return hexafy.myFunc(arg);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input text needs to be parsed into a number:

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return parseInt(x).toString(16);
    };
});
```

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return parseInt(x).toString(16);
    };
})
.controller('ctrl', function($scope,hexafy) {
    $scope.hexVal = 255;
    $scope.hex = function(arg){
        return hexafy.myFunc(arg);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="hexVal">
    <p>Hex service: {{hex(hexVal)}}</p>
</body>
```